# How to add Unicode to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

help me pls.
In Unicode symbol & = "&" + "#38;" If I add it to HTML like this

```
<div id="div" title="&#38;"></div>
```

ALL OK! I create symbol in title, like this

```
div id="div" title="&"></div>
```

But, when I add Unicode in HTML via JavaScript:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.setAttribute('title', "&#38;");
```

I have a bad result:

```
<div id="div" title="&#38;"></div>
```

How I can add Unicode in html attribute via JavaScript and get the correct result like it:

```
<div id="div" title="&"></div>
```

Thanks for help!

AND 
IF I do it:

```
var code = 26;
div.setAttribute('title', "\x" + code);
```

I have a error. How I can fix it?

Comment: JavaScript's `setAttribute` method will correctly HTML-escape values when assigning the attribute value, so you don't need to double escape the attribute, which is what `setAttribute('title', '&#38;')` is doing.

Answer (score 2):

HTML entity escaping (e.g. `&#38;`) is, as the name implies, only necessary in HTML. It's not necessary in Javascript; you can set the character literally:

```
div.setAttribute("title", "&");
```

If you need to escape a character, you can do so using a hexadecimal character escape:

```
div.setAttribute("title", "\x26");
```

or a Unicode character escape:

```
div.setAttribute("title", "\u0026");
```

Comment: How can I get \u0026 ?

Comment: @Gaius_Iulius_Caesar `"\u0026"`

Comment: `var code = 26; div.setAttribute('title', "\x" + code);` - Now I have a error, how I can fix it?

Comment: `"\x"` is not valid syntax; the `\x` escape must be followed by two hex digits, and represents one character. If you want to convert a character code to a character, use `String.fromCharCode()`.

Comment: Can you show me please how i can do it(convert a character code to a character)?

Answer (score 1):

For the `&` character in Javascript, you do not have to escape it. Otherwise, you should can escape Unicode in Javascript with `\u`, but most of the time you will not have to.

Comment: How can I get unicode symbols with \u ?

Comment: @Gaius_Iulius_Caesar `"\u[unicode-goes-here]"`

Comment: `var code = 26;`
`div.setAttribute('title', "\x" + code);`  - Now I have a error, how I can fix it?

Comment: Not sure, @duskwuff?